# How to run a console command on a Heroku app through their REST API?

Tags: heroku, heroku-api

I need to programmatically execute a command on a Heroku app that I created used their REST API. From my console, I'd regularly do it like so:

```
$ heroku run [command]
```

I'm looking for a REST API request like this one:

```
POST /apps/{app_id}/run
```

But I was unable to find it in on the docs and I just resign to acknowledge that's not implemented. It's too much of a default behavior.

I know I could just install the Heroku Toolbelt on the requester box, but I don't like that. I could also set an authenticated URL to fire the thing but that's also too much of a thing for a feature that's already there!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what you're looking for: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#dyno-create

Notice the example there -- you can specify a `run` type which will run the process as a one-off thing. This is exactly how the `heroku run` command works under the hood =)

Comment: Great! Do you know how to pipe the rendezvous URL?

Comment: Oh, got it https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos#timeout-awaiting-process